# "freezing" an input box

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an `<input type="text" />` element. At some point, I don't want it to accept text anymore. For some reason, changing the `type` to `type="button"` for example is not allowed.

How can I make my `<input>` element not accept text anymore?

Comment: Do you want to stop accepting characters because some time has elapsed, some condition has happened, or because they've entered too many characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make it read-only:

```
$('#myInput').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the control with:

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

But be warned, it is still possible for a hacker to manipulate submitted form data. You should ensure that appropriate server-side validation is applied.

If using jQuery you can do the following:

```
HTML:
<input id="my-text-box" type="text" />

JS - jQuery 1.5-:
$('#my-text-box').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
JS - jQuery 1.6+:
$('#my-text-box').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Disabled and READONLY are different. Disabled elements do not get sent to the server when the form is submitted. Readonly elements do.

Comment: @Ariel agreed, I was under the assumption that the data shouldn't be submitted. If it is the case that data should still be submitted simply replace the two words "disabled" with "readonly"

Comment: BTW You should not use `attr()` for disabled. Use `prop()` instead.

Comment: @Ariel any particular reason? `prop` isn't even on the version of jQuery that I am using.

Comment: disabled also disables copy/paste if that matters.

Comment: @lea-hayes because the jQuery team said to? See here: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

Comment: @Ariel thanks for pointing that out, I need to update my project to work with the new version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `READONLY` attribute (property in jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can do `document.getElementById("textbox").disabled = "disabled";`, which will make it read only.